# SSIS - Variable not updating inside loop

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package and am having difficulty getting one simple part of it to work.

I have a loop, for each iteration a stored procedure is called which returns true/false, if true then a package variable is incremented, and a SQL task updates a database record with the newly incremented variable value (shown below).

[image]

This works absolutely fine if I run the package in the designer. However, if I execute the package on SQL Server, or run in a SQL Agent Job, the variable never gets updated from its default of 0.

The variable is of type Int32 and scope defined at package level, and the increment definitely occurs (as mentioned, it works fine with the same data source in the designer).

I have other SQL tasks in the same package and they perform insert/update SQL tasks fine, so it doesn't appear to be a question of access.

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

EDIT

I believe the issue does lie somewhere with the script task, I'm guessing a .NET framework component of some variety is missing on the live server (as one of the comments below alluded to). Have been able to get around the issue for now by doing the increment work in the SQL task instead.

Comment: I saw a similar issue with Script Tasks on some servers that did not have both the x86 and x64 versions of Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications Runtime. See this: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/776248/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-visualstudio-tools-applications-core

Comment: Thanks for that. Afraid I do have both x64 and x86 versions installed on the server though...

Comment: Are you deploying this to the SSISDB?

Comment: Yes. When deployed to the SSISDB and run from there I get the issue of the variable not updating (fine when run locally in the designer).

Comment: How do you know that the stored procedure is ever returning true when called by the SQL Agent?

Comment: Because the SQL - Update Count step is still saving the variable value of 0 (it wouldn't reach this step if true was not returned by the 'True?' task). It is correctly saving the variable value, but this variable should be incremented by the 'Increment Variable' step.

 Script task to increment the variable is doing this: Dts.Variables["User::UpdateRequiredCount"].Value = (int)Dts.Variables["User::UpdateRequiredCount"].Value + 1;